# Book series about a girl without a heart, who has to get the heart of a prince in order to regain her own

Tags: story-identification, books, witches

I remember reading this book a few months back.

It's about a girl, whose parents were killed by bad guys. She was also injured, I think, but a witch offers her revenge or "life" in exchange for her heart. This gives the witch control over the girl. Later, she's chosen to kill the prince. She meets a guy that helps the people who don't have access to medicine, turns out that guy is the prince. They fall in "love" (well the prince does). The girl tries not to give into the "hunger" (a side effect of her heartless-ness) and when it's time for the prince to die, she prevents herself from harming him. The prince is dumbfounded and now he hates her.

I never got to the second book, but it's a series. I'm pretty sure and the cover is a girl in a cape with a white? (or black) crow at the top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[Bring Me Their Hearts](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35144326-bring-me-their-hearts)*** (2018) by Sara Wolf...? It's the first book in a [trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/236050-bring-me-their-hearts).

> **Zera is a Heartless – the immortal, unageing soldier of a witch. Bound to the witch Nightsinger ever since she saved her from the bandits who murdered her family, Zera longs for freedom from the woods they hide in. With her heart in a jar under Nightsinger’s control, she serves the witch unquestioningly.**
>
> **Until Nightsinger asks Zera for a Prince’s heart in exchange for her own,** with one addendum; if she’s discovered infiltrating the court, Nightsinger will destroy her heart rather than see her tortured by the witch-hating nobles.
>
> Crown Prince Lucien d’Malvane hates the royal court as much as it loves him – every tutor too afraid to correct him and every girl jockeying for a place at his darkly handsome side. No one can challenge him – until the arrival of Lady Zera. She’s inelegant, smart-mouthed, carefree, and out for his blood. The Prince’s honor has him quickly aiming for her throat.
>
> So begins a game of cat and mouse between a girl with nothing to lose and a boy who has it all.
>
> Winner takes the loser’s heart.
>
> Literally.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Bring Me Their Hearts" by Sara Wolf.]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!